# Custom environment variables with Popen on Windows on Github Actions

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, github-actions, popen

I'm using `Popen` together with custom environment variables. My expectation is when I run something like this:

```py
    proc = Popen(
        command,
        universal_newlines=True,
        bufsize=0,
        shell=False,
        env=env,
    )
```

that the environment variables set when running `command` are exactly the contents of `env`. However, when I run this on windows machines on github actions, there's (exactly) two additional variables set: `TERM=xterm-256color`, and `HOME=/c/Users/runneradmin`. Interestingly, when I check the contents of `os.environ` **before** execution, there's a lot of variables on the host environment set, **except** those two.

This only happens on windows (running `windows-latest`). On Mac and Linux, the environment is exactly the contents of `env`.

The `command` I'm running in this case is `env` which outputs the environment variables.

My question is, where do those two variables come from and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: What is the command you are running?

Comment: And now that I think of it, could you also share the GH actions job configuration? Are you running on `windows-latest` runner or something self-hosted? Because those seem like cygwin env variables or something.

Comment: I've udpated the question. I'm running windows-latest and here the command is just `env` which puts out the environment variables.

Comment: This vaguely suggests that the Windows version of `env` is some weird nonstandard hack which does something else than what you expect. Does it do the same thing if you run it from outside Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be because GH Actions `cmd.exe` is not really the `cmd` you would expect it to be, but a terminal emulator.

You can verify it with this:

```
      - name: "Print shell"
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          uname -a
          env
```

`uname -a` (a linux command) will print out something like this:

```
MSYS_NT-10.0-20348 fv-az1702-301 3.4.10-87d57229.x86_64 2024-02-14 20:17 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

[MSYS](https://www.msys2.org/) is a windows terminal emulator, that provides a lot of capabilities for building different software on Windows, which is probably why GH Actions uses it by default. It also allows you to run several linux commands on the same terminal, for example the `env` command you mentioned.

It will also set some default env variables, like `TERM=xterm-256color`, which enables colors to the terminal emulator.

`Popen()` will then try to use this default cmd, which is why those environment variables are then pre-set when you run `env`.